# Google Webfont not displaying on GAE site

Tags: google-app-engine, webfonts, google-webfonts

So I'm trying to use a Google Webfont on a GAE site. The font works when I browse the site locally, but after I deploy and go to the .appspot.com address, the font no longer works and defaults to "cursive".

Here's the relevant code:

CSS:

```
.logo {
  font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nothing+You+Could+Do' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
</head>
<a class="logo" href="/">Project</a>
```

Comment: I don't see anything that might be wrong, can u try some other font type if it works, am using the "Tangerine" with the same syntax as urs. seems to be working well.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it and it didn't work either. However, it did load in IE (I was previously using Chrome). So I'm thinking this might be a browser problem...any ideas?

Comment: You may try to use the appspot.com address _and_ another domain you have pointing to the same app and see if there is anything different. Also, you should have your debugging console open to check if everything is downloading correctly (or triggering an error)

Comment: Strange, I just checked the site today and the font was displaying. Didn't change anything since yesterday either. The problem seems to have resolved itself....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a browser issue.

Quoting from [here](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/faq#Browsers_Unsupported):

> What browsers are supported? The Google Web Fonts API is compatible
>   with the following browsers:
>
> Google Chrome: version 4.249.4+ Mozilla Firefox: version: 3.5+ Apple
>   Safari: version 3.1+ Opera: version 10.5+ Microsoft Internet Explorer:
>   version 6+
>
> What do unsupported browsers see? If someone using an unsupported
>   browser visits a page that uses the Web Fonts API, then the text is
>   displayed using the next available font in your CSS font stack.

Comment: Might've just been a temporary bug, it's working in Chrome now.